# The problem that Precision loss in big.Float

Tags: go

While running:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    a := big.NewFloat(float64(2.1234))
    fmt.Println(a.Text(102,18))
}
```

I expected 2.123400000000000000 as output, but instead got 2.123400000000000176.

Can someone explain me why I do not have the expected number?

Comment: Ask yourself: Can 2.1234 be represented _exactly_ as a float64? If no: As which float64 would this be represented? This should fix your expectations (which are wrong, the value printed is the correct one).

Comment: I just want calc 1.2345 * 10 ^ 18.  i use big.Float mult big.Float, so i trans 1.2345 to big.Float

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> big.NewFloat(float64(2.1234))
> ```

`float64(2.1234)` converts to Go `float64` (IEEE-754 64-bit floating-point), which has 53 bits of precision.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    // 53 bits of precision (float64)
    a := big.NewFloat(float64(2.1234))
    fmt.Println(a.Text(102, 18))

    x := "2.1234"

    // 53 bits of precision
    f, _, err := big.ParseFloat(x, 10, 53, big.ToNearestEven)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(f.Text(102, 18))

    // 256 bits of precision
    f, _, err = big.ParseFloat(x, 10, 256, big.ToNearestEven)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(f.Text(102, 18))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/z5iK90lQcD9

Output:

```
2.123400000000000176
2.123400000000000176
2.123400000000000000
```